# Creating a php program to compare video game characters

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "jmpmvp", "characters");
if ($connect){
    echo "connected<br>";

}
$query = "SELECT * FROM `character`";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action ="handler.php" method="post">
            <label for="character">SELECT A CHARACTER </label>
        <select multiple name="character">
            <?php while($character = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){?>
            <option value ="<?php echo $character['id'];?>"</option>
             <?php echo $character['name'];?></option>
            <?php }?> 

        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my index page above

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "jmpmvp", "characters");
if ($connect){
    echo "connected<br>";

}
$query = "SELECT * FROM `character` where id = ". $_POST ["character"];
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>



            <?php while($character = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){?>

              <?php echo $character["name"];?><br>;
             <?php echo $character["attack"];?><br> ;
             <?php echo $character["defense"];?><br>;
            <?php } ?>


    </body>
</html>
```

alright here is my handler page the issue I am  having is I can select multiple options in my html select on my index page but I am having a problem displaying when multiple characters are selected in my handler page.  Does anyone know how to fix this specific issue? I also want the data to displayed in a table which I'm pretty sure I can figure out.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service**! You have to show that you've put some efford into solving your own problem.

Comment: You need to break your question down into smaller parts. What are you trying to accomplish? Where are you getting stuck? Nobody is going to be able to help you with such a specific question

Comment: Sorry first time user of this site and about 3 months into php so I'm still learning.  This project is a little advanced for me obviously but all the forums said to do something you like and you will learn quicker.  I just rewrote my question and any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What You have to do is get data from database and then put them into HTML <select> tag. After that, when You will have some code, You may ask again where did You stuck.

Comment: Alright thanks for giving me a starting point

Comment: Added what I have by doing what you said with the select tag, please let me know if I am on the right track.  I read about onchange events, is that what I am looking to do to link my drop down selection to a new table that will be displayed on the site?

Comment: It depends how You want this to work. `onchange` event is JavaScript. If you are new into programming I would recommend You to stay away from this by now and stay with PHP and HTML with some CSS. Read about `<form>` tag now and handle it in PHP. POST and GET requests will be Your homework.Then show the code with exact question/problem actually.

Comment: Alright thanks again yeah I'm new only about a month or two into learning about it so I understand a lot of the syntax I just don't know where to start when making things from scratch

Comment: Wll if You know a syntax, but don't know where to start then You don't know enough. Read some tutorial of PHP it will help You.

Answer (score 0):

What You actually need is logical approach. You have to ask yourself a question "what You want", "what You need" and "how to do it".

So in Your case You want to compare something but You didn't actually say what exactly You need. So if You're new i can can help You that:

What You need for sure is webpage, where user can select character from a list. But what then? I don't know. You didn't specify so...:

1) Show user a select box to choose character. How to get them? Select from database. This is what You already have.

2) After user select character You need to send this data to the server. How to do it? Use `<form>` tag like:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="character">...option list...</select>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

3) Get data sent by Your form and use them to compare with... something You have.

```
<?php

if( isset( $_POST['character'] ) ){
// do something with this character
}

?>
```

4) Show user response like found or not found or something else. Pass this data into some div like:

```
<?php
$found = 'set this true OR false';

if( $found ){
    $message = 'Found it!';
}else{
    $message = 'Not_found!";
}

?>
```

Then in HTML write something like:

```
<div><?php echo isset( $message ) ? $message : ''; ?></div>
```

Thats it, rest is up to You. Any simple problem You will solve by searching in Google.

**-------- Edit**

First of all if You're using multiple select box, the name must be:

```
<select name="character[]" multiple>
```

Then Your $_POST['character'] is now an array. You can check its content by:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Use foreach:

```
$ids = []; // or $ids = array(); if php version lower than 5.4

foreach( $_POST['character'] as $v ){
    $ids []= (int) $v;
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `character` where id IN ('. implode(',', $ids) .') ';
```

Comment: Here is my index page

Comment: thanks for your explanation i'm going to look into what you posted more but what I am trying to do is the following. Take my database which contains characters name, attack rating, defense rating.  1- display the characters name in a drop down to be picked by the user 2- allow the the user to allow multiple selections of characters from the drop down 3- display the choices in a table.  After I figure this out I want to be able to compare one character against another character, but I am trying to start small and develop it more after

Comment: Will my query on my handler have to be changed now that I am selecting multiple options?